# Would a software developer candidate's tech blog be looked at during the hiring process?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, resume, hiring-process, blogging

[This podcast episode](https://www.bikeshed.fm/351), (with a transcript) is about learning in public, in the context of software development, where having a tech blog is one example of that. The episode contains the following claims:

> I think learning in public ... helps you stand out amongst other candidates that are applying for a job.

> But at the same time, [learning in public is] also proving to everyone that you are good at communicating or that you have grown a lot in your communication.

I want to hear about experiences candidates have had where having a blog clearly affected whether they were hired. I would also like to hear about experiences folks doing the hiring have had where they either did or did not look at a candidate's blog, and what effect that had on their decision, if any.

I tend to agree with the podcast episode's broader thesis that learning in public is a good way to learn more/faster. (I expect most regular Stack Exchange users would also agree.) However, I'm less sure whether writing tech blog posts would actually affect a candidate's chances of being hired in a meaningful way.

Note that this is a different question from whether a very popular blog post could spark the interest of an employer. I want to know, given a candidate replies to a company's job ad, when there had been no prior contact, whether a tech blog that is mentioned somewhere in the application would be looked at, more often than not.

I don't currently have a tech blog. When a job application form has included a place to put a personal website, I've just put a link to my Github account, where I have several software side-projects available to view. My current impression is that almost no employers are going to take more than a glance at a candidate's available code, given the chance, and most not even that.

My goal when asking this question is to decide whether making a tech blog would be worth the effort, if we consider only the effect it would have on hiring decisions.

Any impression is a chance for a good impression. But a non-impression is not.

The host and guest on that podcast episode work for the same software consultancy/agency. Maybe looking at candidate's blog when hiring is a phenomenon specific to software consultancies/agencies?

That same company also has their own tech blog. Perhaps only companies that already have their own tech blog, (as opposed to entirely marketing posts,) would care about this?

Overall, my question is, would a large enough percentage of employers look at a candidate's tech blog to make it worth writing one for that reason alone?

Comment: *"I want to hear more opinions on whether or not the average company hiring one or more software developers would actually look at a blog that was mentioned in a job application"* - asking for opinions is off-topic. I feel that we can only guess on such percentage or probability... *"Maybe looking at candidate's blog when hiring is a phenomenon specific to software consultancies/agencies "* - perhaps, and that would make it company/industry specific (also off-topic)... bottom line, I fear that what you ask is not something we can help you with as it lacks a goal and would be guessing at best.

Comment: relevant answer to a slightly different question: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/6675/102

Comment: @DarkCygnus I see that sharing experiences over opinions is encouraged [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), so I have edited the post to ask for experiences instead. I see that company specific advice is listed as off-topic [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but I find the idea that industry specific questions are off topic to be strange. Why does the software-industry tag exist then? I've also edited the post to try to make it clear what I consider the goal of this question is

Comment: Jobs that have a public facing aspect (tech evangelists, developer relationship folks, community managers, etc.), are more likely to care that you have a blog. For some of those roles they may also care about the size of your audience though.

Comment: @Ryan1729 I commend your effort in editing and improving your post :). Company-specific questions are off-topic because they are not useful for the rest of the readers and members of the community (and are also hard to answer unless you work on that company; most of them boil down to "ask your manager" or "read your contract")... I mentioned "industry specific" because you mentioned "specific to software companies", and what I wanted to convey is that in industry/company A the *opinion* would be different than in industry/company B [regarding a tech blog]. Emphasis on opinion and not industry.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Just so I understand the expectations here, was this question closed because what I wrote was misinterpreted as a backhanded way of asking about a specific singular company? (To be clear, that was not my intention!) Or is asking about a subset of companies within a particular industry, even if that subset has multiple multiple members, in this example those that have tech blogs, considered off-topic here?

Answer (score 7):

I think you can be certain that a tech blog is looked at during the hiring process. Most employers will google you, look at your facebook or other social media. Github will also be viewed, but reading code is hard, so this will only be relevant if you are one of the top selected candidates.

Can it hurt you having a blog? Well, depends on the quality. If your blog is full of spelling mistakes and unprofessional jokes it won't help you to find a job. If it shows the hard problems you have solved during your professional career, and showcases how passionate you are about what you are doing, it certainly helps you stand out in the candidate pool.